# Extjs4.2 filter on one column and user can use separator to match different rows

Tags: filter, extjs4.2, separator

I have to filter on one column, and user can use separator to match different rows, like this: (As I couldn't post images, I have to describle the menuitme for my column)

```
Sort Ascending
Sort Descending
Filters =>  Jim|Tom
```

User could enter "Jim|Tom" in the Textbox to filter on the Grid.

But Generally, it seems not supported by Extjs 4.2. I found that apply multiple values for one property does not work like above.

Here is my column definition for this column 'Owner':

```
{   
    text:'Owner',
    width:50,
    dataIndex:'owner',
    sortable:true,
    filter:{
    type:'string',
    }
},
```

How could I solver this problem?

Thanks.

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to override string filter, something like (untested):

```
Ext.define('MyOverride', {
   override: 'Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilter',

    validateRecord : function (record) {
        var val = record.get(this.dataIndex);

        if(typeof val != 'string') {
            return (this.getValue().length === 0);
        }
        val = val.toLowerCase();
        var parts = this.getValue().toLowerCase().split('|'),
            found = false;

        Ext.Array.forEach(parts, function(part) {
            if (val.indexOf(part) > -1) {
                found = true;
            }
        });

        return found;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is what I want. 
Let me try this.
Thank you so much Evan.